# how to Input polygon featuer using Rubber poly (ArcObjects)

Tags: polygon, arcobjects, c#, geometry

Does any one know how to input polygon feature using Rubber poly?
I would like to know how to input Polygon featurer using rubber poly..
as of now i can input polygon feature. but some times , polygon are is negative value and can not show the label etc..

I assume i need to something about geometry setting.. but i do not know how to do it...

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs arg)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(arg);
    IMxDocument pMxDocument = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
    IMap pMap = pMxDocument.FocusMap;

    IRubberBand pRubber = new RubberPolygon();
    IPolygon pPolygon = pRubber.TrackNew(pMxDocument.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay, null) as IPolygon;

    IFeatureLayer pFLayer = pMap.Layer[0] as IFeatureLayer;
    IWorkspaceEdit pWorkspaceEdit = ((IDataset)(pFLayer.FeatureClass)).Workspace as IWorkspaceEdit;

    pWorkspaceEdit.StartEditing(false);
    pWorkspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

    IFeature pFeature = pFLayer.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
    pFeature.Shape = pPolygon;

    pFeature.Store();

    pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
    pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
    pMxDocument.ActiveView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like an incorrect ring orientation, you might need to simplify the polygon, use ITopologicalOperator4.Simplify http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/000100000304000000.htm probably set IsKnownSimple to false first though.

Comment: thank you very much. i could solve label probrem.
All polygon can show label. but still i can not identify some polygon.,,
Do i need to do something more  ?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What happens when you have a polygon you can't identify?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  When i use ITopologicalOperator4.Simplify .I could solve label probrem. and also  I found out why i can not identify some polygon... Actually another code have probrem( delete polygon on mouse click). but i already fix it. thank you very much...

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to post your working code as an answer to your own question with an explanation and links to the objects in the Esri help.